# what is name of this plugin used for photo gallery page

Tags: plugins, gallery

i need to now what is name of this plugin that's  used for image gallery page in this [site](http://www.alexwisephotography.net/blog/portfolio/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the document source, the site is loading scripts from the [NextGen Gallery Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/).